# Conversion from type 'Font' to type 'String' is not valid VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, fonts, vb6, vb6-migration

I have a project that I have converted from VB6 to VB.NET using Visual Studio 2008. I have an line of code that throws and an error at run time, but not in compiling. The line of worked well in VB6. The code:

```
SizingLabel.Font = VB6.FontChangeName(SizingLabel.Font, FromObject.Font)
```

The error is:

> Conversion from type 'Font' to type 'String' is not valid.

I am not sure why it is throwing an `InvalidCastException` I thought font was a string. I tried to add `.ToString()` to everything, but when I do that I get an error in the IDE:

> Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Font'.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use FromObject.Font.FamilyName

Answer (score 1):

In VB.net the Font property returns an object of type Font.  To change the font assign a different Font object to the property,

```
SizingLabel.Font = new Font(FromObject.Font, FromObject.Font.Style)
```

The confusion might result from using a property for a different type object than it's name would indicate.  If `FromObject.Font` is a string representing a Font Family, and not a Font object, then this should work:

```
SizingLabel.Font = new Font(FromObject.Font, 10)
```

The `10` represents the size of the font.  There's also an option to set the FontStyle as well.

Comment: I tried that code, and I recived the following error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Sub New(familyName As String, emSize As Single)': Argument matching parameter 'familyName' narrows from 'Object' to 'String'.
    'Public Sub New(familyName As String, emSize As Single)': Argument matching parameter 'emSize' narrows from 'Object' to 'Single'.
    'Public Sub New(family As System.Drawing.FontFamily, emSize As Single)': Argument matching parameter 'family' narrows from 'Object' to 'System.Drawing.FontFamily'.

Comment: I added another option.

Comment: Well I changed it to VB6.FontChangeName(SizingLabel.Font, 10) to get it to work. Is there a why for me to not have to use VB6.FontChanged? When I used the SizingLabel.Font = new Font(FromObject.Font, 10) I get the error: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion

Comment: Is the Font property of FromObject a Font or a string?